# After upgrade chef server, cannot boostrap application

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

We have chef-server 12.3.1 and all applications can bootstrap with no problems on the nodes.

After upgrade to chef-server 12.19.26 we cannot bootstrap our application. We can install npm, nginx and others but our application raise the error on chef: FrozenError class.

[image]

Now we know that we are using Ruby 2.5 and this class was introduced on this verson.

We are checking the problem with no success yet.

We would like to know how to by pass this problem.

Comment: what is the chef-client version and did you check whether your recipes are compatible with that version?

Comment: Hi looks like your chef-client version is updated and your recipes are not supported, please check you chef client version.